# Не работает выпадающее меню

Tags: html, css

```css
.up {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 20%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(110, 22, 62, .9);
 z-index: 5;

}
nav .menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4rem;

}
.wrapp {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
 
 display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}


ul {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  }


ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  
}

ul.menu>li>a {


  display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;


}

ul.menu>li:hover>a:not(:only-child) {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #17191b;
  background-color: #17191b;
}
ul.menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #17191b;
  border: 0px solid #fff;

}


ul.submenu-1 {
  display: none;
   position: absolute;

  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}
ul.submenu-2 {
  display: none;
   position: absolute;

  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}

ul.submenu-1>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-2>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-1>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}
ul.submenu-2>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}


ul.submenu-1>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #17191b;
}
ul.submenu-2>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #17191b;
}
ul.menu>li:hover>ul.submenu-1 {
  display: block;
 
}
ul.menu>li:hover>ul.submenu-2 {
  display: block;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
<nav class="wrapp">       
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Наши услуги</a></li> 
      <ul class="submenu-1">
       <li><a href="">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="">3</a></li>
      </ul>
     <li><a href="">Меню</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
      <ul class="submenu-2">
       <li><a href="">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="">3</a></li>
      </ul>
     <li><a href="">Контакты<a></li>   
    </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .up {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 20%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(110, 22, 62, .9);
 z-index: 5;

}
nav .menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4rem;

}
.wrapp {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
 
 display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}


ul {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
  }


ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  
}

ul.menu>li>a {


  display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;


}

ul.menu>li:hover>a:not(:only-child) {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #17191b;
  background-color: #17191b;
}
ul.menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #17191b;
  border: 0px solid #fff;

}


ul.submenu-1 {
  display: none;
   position: absolute;

  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}
ul.submenu-2 {
  display: none;
   position: absolute;

  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}

ul.submenu-1>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-2>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-1>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}
ul.submenu-2>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}


ul.submenu-1>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #17191b;
}
ul.submenu-2>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #17191b;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>ul {
 display: block;
}

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="up">
  <nav class="wrapp">       
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Наши услуги</a>
     <ul class="submenu-1">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Меню</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О компании</a>
     <ul class="submenu-2">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Контакты<a></li>   
   </ul>
     </nav>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```